# Git: Create commits in featurebranch that are harmful in upstream

Tags: git

When I develop inside a feature branch I make some initial commits to setup the branch for the specific task. These commits I do not want to have in the upstream later. Is there a way to prevent the merge of these "preparation commits" when going back to merge origin?

Maybe a name for these commits would be "branch-local-commits" or "unmergable commits"

Here is an image clarifying the intent

```
master: *--*--*--*--*----------------Merge (only B,C)
                    \--A(prep)--B--C/
```

Comment: [Rebase Interactive?](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode)

Comment: Yes, rebase -i works but I want to force-prevent the merge. The reason is that when a branch is running for months you forget the prep-commit (sometimes :))

Answer (score 0):

When you're ready to merge your feature branch, you can either:

- revert the changes in `A`, using `git revert A`.

  This would make sure that the commits `B` and `C` get merged *exactly* into the main branch in the form they are now. It would also make both `A` and its reversal part of the history of the main branch.
- rebase the feature branch to drop `A`, using `git rebase -i`.

  This would re-create `B` and `C` on top of the main branch. The commit message, patch and author would be taken from the original `B` and `C` commits, but the committer info would be modified to indicate that you've created new commits. `A` would not be visible in the main branch, and after rebasing, would not be visible in the feature branch either.

What I personally do for changes of this sort, which could work for you in the future but not right now, is not commit them at all. I keep them as local changes, in a form that allows me to easily apply and unapply them as needed, and unapply them before creating large commits to make sure I don't include them by accident.

Comment: I used both but was not that happy because when I merge I might have forgotten what I wanted to remove later. But reading your last section maybe I can keep the prep-Changes as stashs and apply them as needed?

Comment: @schoetbi Sure, that could work too. It's easier to apply stashes than local patch files, but slightly more tricky to unapply them while still preserving your other changes. If that's not a problem for you, go for it.